# Autolayout UITableViewCells covering up bottom

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios-autolayout

I'm having trouble with this UITableViewCell. I'm getting strings from a server and inserting it in viewDidLoad, but the bottom of the cell, namely summaryLabel is being covered up. Is it the inset? [Here's the code](https://gist.github.com/YoomamaFTW/a6e81d5232be5716362909c3588673b2):

```
class SummaryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let createdLabel = UILabel()
    let summaryLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2
        titleLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)

        summaryLabel.numberOfLines = 4
        summaryLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
        titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        createdLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        summaryLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(createdLabel)
        contentView.addSubview(summaryLabel)
        let lg = contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            titleLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: createdLabel.topAnchor),

            createdLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            createdLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            createdLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: summaryLabel.topAnchor, constant: -8),

            summaryLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor),
            summaryLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor),
            summaryLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        contentView.frame = contentView.frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 17, bottom: 15, right: 17))
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder)}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix autolayout with frame layout represented by setting the `frame` of `contentView` , so Substitue with constant

```
titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.topAnchor,constant:15), 
summaryLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.bottomAnchor,constant:-15)
```

and change leading & trailing for all lbls to something like this

```
titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.leadingAnchor,constant:17),
titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: lg.trailingAnchor,constant:-17),
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, which can save some effort and can make it easier to adjust if you decide to:

```
contentView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 17, bottom: 15, right: 17)
let lg = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide
```

Then you can leave your constraints as-is (without needing to set all the constants), and you can remove your `layoutSubviews()` func completely.